# How to implement Spring Boot Microservice with two levels of token authentication using Spring Security?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt, microservices

**Hello Team,**

I am working on a Spring Boot project in which I want to setup two levels of token authentication using Spring Security + JWT.

A similar application has already been built by some of my colleagues using Dropwizard framework.

I want to implement the same architecture in my Spring Boot project. I have added link to the architecture of the API at the end of this question.

I am able to setup the first level of token authentication with Spring Boot (using Spring Security + JWT), but I am unable to find the correct way of setting up second level of token authentication.

I tried searching out for related articles but couldn't find any.

It would be helpful if you could share a code snippet implementing both levels of token authentication in Spring Boot (using Spring Security) for better understanding.

Thanking you in anticipation!

[image: Refer Web API Architecture here.]

Comment: implementing any type of custom security flows are bad practice. There are numerous examples of badly implemented flows which has lead to security breaches. You should follow any of the standard oauth2 flows, or use the current existing authentication methods provided by spring that have been reviewed and tested by the community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is a **proof of concept** to achieve what you need. The first class is the security configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

   public static final List<String> WHITE_LIST = asList("/authenticate");
   public static final List<String> TOKEN1_LIST = asList("/get-access-token");
   public static final List<String> TOKEN2_LIST = asList("/add-new-user");

   @Autowired
   private Token1Filter token1Filter;

   @Autowired
   private Token2Filter token2Filter;


   @Override
   protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
     http.csrf().disable()
            .formLogin().disable()
            .httpBasic().disable()
            // Make sure we use stateless session; session won't be used to store user's state
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
            // Handle an authorized attempts
            .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint((req, rsp, e) -> rsp.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED))
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            // List of services do not require authentication
            .antMatchers(OPTIONS).permitAll()
            .antMatchers(GET, WHITE_LIST.toArray(new String[WHITE_LIST.size()])).permitAll()
            // Any other request must be authenticated
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .addFilterBefore(token1Filter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .addFilterBefore(token2Filter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
  }
}
```

As you can see, the different Urls are included in different properties and every `List` related with them is configured in `HttpSecurity` class. The filters used to manage every subset, I mean, Urls securized using Jwt 1 and Jwt 2 are the following ones:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@Component
public class Token1Filter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

  private static final String TOKEN_PREFIX = "Bearer ";

  @Override
  protected void doFilterInternal (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                                 FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
    getJwt(request)
            .ifPresent(jwt1 -> {
                /**
                 *    Here you can use functionality to check provided Jwt token 1,
                 * adding included data into Spring SecurityContextHolder.
                 */

                // Used for testing purpose
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(
                        new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken("testUserToken1", null, new ArrayList<>())
                );
            });
    filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
  }


  @Override
  protected boolean shouldNotFilter(HttpServletRequest request) throws ServletException {
    return !WebSecurityConfiguration.TOKEN1_LIST.contains(request.getRequestURI());
  }


  private Optional<String> getJwt(HttpServletRequest request) {
    return ofNullable(request)
            .map(r -> r.getHeader(AUTHORIZATION))
            .filter(Predicate.not(String::isEmpty))
            .map(t -> t.replace(TOKEN_PREFIX, ""))
            .filter(Predicate.not(String::isEmpty));
  }
}



@AllArgsConstructor
@Component
public class Token2Filter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

  private static final String TOKEN_PREFIX = "Bearer ";

  @Override
  protected void doFilterInternal (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                                 FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
    getJwt(request)
            .ifPresent(jwt2 -> {
                /**
                 *    Here you can use functionality to check provided Jwt token 2,
                 * adding included data into Spring SecurityContextHolder.
                 */

                // Used for testing purpose
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(
                        new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken("testUserToken2", null,
                                asList(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ADMIN")))
                );
            });
    filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
  }


  @Override
  protected boolean shouldNotFilter(HttpServletRequest request) throws ServletException {
    return !WebSecurityConfiguration.TOKEN2_LIST.contains(request.getRequestURI());
  }


  private Optional<String> getJwt(HttpServletRequest request) {
    return ofNullable(request)
            .map(r -> r.getHeader(AUTHORIZATION))
            .filter(Predicate.not(String::isEmpty))
            .map(t -> t.replace(TOKEN_PREFIX, ""))
            .filter(Predicate.not(String::isEmpty));
  }
}
```

Every one include an implementation of `shouldNotFilter` method to know if it have to manage the current request. And contains a comment on location on which you need to add the functionality to extract and verify the provided Jwt token.

And finally, only a dummy controller to test every use case:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@RestController
public class TestController {

  @GetMapping("/authenticate")
  public ResponseEntity<String> authenticate(@RequestParam String username, @RequestParam String password) {
    return new ResponseEntity("[authenticate] Testing purpose", OK);
  }

  @GetMapping("/get-access-token")
  public ResponseEntity<String> getAccessToken() {
    return new ResponseEntity("[get-access-token] Testing purpose", OK);
  }

  @GetMapping("/add-new-user")
  @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ADMIN')")
  public ResponseEntity<String> addNewUser() {
    return new ResponseEntity("[add-new-user] Testing purpose", OK);
  }
}
```

Several improvements could be added but this is a good initial point that works as expected.

Comment: if you provide a token that is not prefixed by `Bearer` but anything else it will pass your little validation. Implementing custom security filters are bad practice and there are numerous examples of badly implemented custom spring security filters.

Comment: On the other hand, few things to take into account: **1.** `Bearer` prefix is an standard so it makes sense here. **2.** Due to the Urls not included in "whitelist" have been configured as `authenticated()`, your affirmation `anything else it will pass your little validation` is not true. **3.** In the example, data included in `SecurityContextHolder` is only used as testing purpose, if you read the above comment, I explain him how every use case has to be manage. **4.** If you need a custom security approach but Spring does not provide it natively, the solution cannot be `don't do it`

Comment: Something that is bad practice should not be answered with a proof of concept. It should be answered with that it is bad practice. If you need custom security someone has done something wrong in the first place. There are standards that should be followed, and we should teach such standards. Anything else is a wrong answer. We should not answer people with bad practices.

Comment: Create a custom filter is a tool provided by the framework and a technique widely used. You persist still calling it `bad practice`, ok, feel free to talk with Spring team about it. I called `proof of concept` because I don't know the details about how to deal with his Jwt tokens, so I cannot "fill the gaps". For that reason, I included comments in the code on which those ones should be managed and added required content into Spring Authorization stuff.

Comment: On the other hand, I would like to know what is the security problem of the provided answer. If the token doesn't include `Bearer` prefix it doesn't a problem, `getJwt` still returns the included one, and below every  comment, the required functionality to manage them should be added. All endpoints not included in the `whitellist` must be authenticated, so what are the security problem with that configuration?

Comment: Finally, I still waiting for your answer to know the good way to do it. I like learn. Because, of course, to say `the framework doesn't provide a native way to do it, so don't do it`, is not an option if you work as developer.

Comment: creating a filter is not bad practice, implementing a custom security solution is. If doing such with a filter or any other measure is bad practice. Period. The provided answer per say does not include any security issues YET. But saying that something is possible, just because you can, doesnt mean it is a good idea and should be provided as an answer. This is not an answer, this is teaching someone bad practice.

Comment: Just because you CAN doesn't mean you SHOULD.

Comment: `The provided answer per say does not include any security issues YET`. Yes, that is the point. Who develops the code should know what he/she is doing. If there is a problem, ok, solve it, but that only is required when you make a mistake. The advice should not be `don't do it in that way because you can make a mistake`. In every part of the code, you can make one

Comment: `the framework doesn't provide a native way to do it, so don't do it` Is the exact correct answer. Because what they have done is made up a custom security solution, THAT IS BAD PRACTICE. There is no native way, because it is NOT one of the standards out there. Standards are there because they have been tested and PROVEN safe if implemented correctly. The correct answer here is that they should look at some of already well defined authentication flows provided by for example oauth2 and use that instead of making up their own custom flow.

Comment: this is not an answer, because it is encouraging bad practice.

Comment: The standards change every time. In this profession you CANNOT say, `that is not an standard, don't do it` because "the real world" works in a different way. If you need to custom "whatever": learn, be careful develop it, test, test, test and test.

Comment: you should always follow standards in security. Always.

Comment: https://mrsuicideparrot.github.io/security/2020/07/30/CVE-2020-15957.html

Comment: The solution provided by @doctore works perfectly.

Considering the best practices, this was an already implemented architecture in a existing project of a client so I had no choice rather than following the same.

However, I have done the necessary changes as suggested in the article shared by Thomas Andolf for token parsing using JJWT library.

Thank you doctore and Thomas Andolf for the help.